Adding the Number of Pages in 2 Sections of a Word Document
I am creating a Word document, the main body of which comprises 2 sections (Section 1 and Section 2) followed by a number of appendices, which are also separate sections.
Page numbers X of Y are displayed in the header of both the main document and the appendices.
I have used the {PAGE} (X) and {SECTIONPAGES} (Y) fields to count the total number of pages in each appendix and this works well.
My problem is with the page numbering of the main body of the document, which comprises 2 sections. Section 1 is the cover page so will only ever be 1 page long. Section 2 forms the rest of the main body and will vary in length (I intend to use the same template for several different documents).
For both sections I am using {PAGE} to generate the X value and for Section 2 I have started page numbering at page 2, so it follows on from Section 1. For the Y value in both Section 1 and Section 2 I want to display the total number of pages in Sections 1 and 2 (not the whole document) but I cannot work out how to do this and allow the number of pages in Section 2 to be variable.
Does anybody have the answer please? Many thanks in advance!

there is no reason to ask Does anybody have the answer please? ... this is a Q&A site ... if someone knows the answer. then they'll share ... or is that your actual question and you only want a yes or no answer?

You will find the answer in this page from Greg Maxey http://gregmaxey.com/word_tip_pages/page_numbering.html.

@CharlesKenyon thanks very much for your response. I did what I needed to do with the  page by Greg Maxey, but in my case (since I am producing a template that will be used for others to produce a number of documents) this is not totally robust since someone could inadvertently delete the word that has been bookmarked. Is there another way to do this that doesn't rely on the bookmark and PageRef field? Thanks.

Not that I am aware of.
